# Axios Post Error - Connection Refused for Spotify API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Would very much appreciate help figuring out why i am receiving an error in my axios post request. New to using APIs and would also love to know how I can best error handle things like this.

```
const express = require('express');
const spotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/refresh', (req, res) => {
    const refreshToken = req.body.refreshToken;
    console.log(refreshToken)
    const spotifyApi = new spotifyWebApi({
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
        clientId: '34203c820a8a49b783fb4588f1b241df',
        clientSecret: '9343f7f9db05463cbf2c1b9532b9137e',
        refreshToken,
    })

    spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken().then(
    (data) => {
        res.json({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
        })

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.sendStatus(400)

    }) 
});
       
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const code = req.body.code;
    const spotifyApi = new spotifyWebApi({
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
        clientId: '34203c820a8a49b783fb4588f1b241df',
        clientSecret: /
    })


    spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(data => {
    res.json({
        accessToken: data.body.access_token,
        refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
        expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
    })

    }).catch(()=> {
    res.sendStatus(400)
    })

});

app.listen(3001);
```

Please let me know if you need anything else to help me solve this problem.

Tried commenting out catch handle to home page,
[following webdev simplified spotify tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xcet6msf3eE)

Answer (score 1):

Four items are wrong.

#1 You don't need to serve `app.post`, it needs to change into `app.get`

The POST API call, will call inside `spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken()` and `spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant()`

The express just response `app.get()` for the user's browser access.

The `axois` POST is not related to this question.

#2 The app.get("/callback") will call by Spotify server, you needs to capture `code` and forward to the `spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code)`, that part is missing

#3 You missed set tokens to the spotifyApi.
It helps to get the next access token by refreshAccessToken()

```
// save access token
spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body.access_token);

// save refresh token
spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body.refresh_token);
```

#4 Miss match Express callback port and redirect port number.

Express use 3001

```
app.listen(3001);
```

Redirect URI use 3000

```
http://localhost:3000
```

***Both should be a match***

This demo code will work

Save as `demo.js` file name.

```js
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node')
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")

const app = express()
app.use(cors())

PORT = 3000

const scopes = ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email'] // you need to add a scope, it depends on your API call
const state = 'what-ever-your-state'

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: 'your client ID',
    clientSecret: 'your client secret',
    redirectUri: `http://localhost:${PORT}/callback`    // my redirectURL is `localhost:3000/callback`
});

app.get("/login", (request, response) => {
    var authorizeURL = spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes, state);
    response.redirect(authorizeURL);
})

app.get("/callback", async (request, response) => {
    const code = request.query["code"]
    spotifyApi.authorizationCodeGrant(code).then(data => {
        // save access token
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body.access_token);

        // save refresh token
        spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(data.body.refresh_token);

        // show tokens in browser
        return response.send(JSON.stringify({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            refreshToken: data.body.refresh_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
        }));
    }).catch(() => {
        response.sendStatus(400)
    })
})

app.get("/refresh", async (request, response) => {
    spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken().then(data => {
        // save access token
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body.access_token);

        // show token in browser
        return response.send(JSON.stringify({
            accessToken: data.body.access_token,
            expiresIn: data.body.expires_in,
        }));
    }).catch(() => {
        response.sendStatus(400)
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on :${PORT}`)
})
```

#### Install dependencies

```
npm install spotify-web-api-node express cors
```

#### Run it

```
node demo.js
```

#### Log in

```
http://localhost:3000/login
```

It will display an access token and a refresh token.

[image]

#### Get New Access Token by refreshing the token API

```
http://localhost:3000/refresh
```

[image]

#### Demo Result

[image]

#### Reference

[Spotify Web API Node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node)